# Make Chrome respond to custom keys?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got a few keys on my keyboard (not macros) that I would like to make Chrome respond to via an extension.

For example:
On www.domain.com
When X button is pressed, simulate a click on `<div id="button"></div>`

Any suggestions how I could even get started?

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining a content-script. The following manifest would run `my-content-script.js` when landing on `http(s)://www.domain.com/*`.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["*://www.domain.com/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.domain.com/*"],
      "js": ["my-content-script.js""],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
    ]
}
```

Then in your content script (my-content-script.js) you can use a `keyDown` event handler to capture when X is pressed and click a button.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 88) {
        alert("X Pressed so let's click the button!!");
        document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();
    }
};
```

A full list of `keyCode`s is available at [Cambia Research](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).